# Is there a transaction isolation level equivalent to the READCOMMITTEDLOCK table hint?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, isolation-level, hint

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments) makes it clear that you can use the `READCOMMITTEDLOCK` table hint to get the default `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED` behaviour when the non-default `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` option is enabled. Is there a transaction isolation level equivalent to this? That is, when the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` option is enabled, is there a transaction isolation level that would let me act if it is disabled and I'm running under a `READ COMMITTED` isolation level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT option is enabled, is there a transaction isolation level that would let me act if it is disabled and I'm running under a READ COMMITTED isolation level?

No.  But REPEATABLE READ and SERIALIZABLE will force reading with S locks.